# FME test for #1.QNAN value

Tags: coordinates, fme-form, null, smallworld-gis

I have an FME workspace, part of which looks like this:

[image]

Incoming features may have point geometry or may not, this is because source data is smallworld, where geometry is a non-mandatory attribute.

The `CoordinateExtractor` transformer is set up like this:

[image]

When incoming feature has no geometry, return value for `_x` and `_y` attribute is `#1.QNAN` which means 'quiet not a number', as I've learned so far, and means something like `NULL` value.

**The question is**, how to test for this value in the `Tester` transformer, as far as I see, `Attribute has null value` test does not work.

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with smallworld?

Comment: We could discuss about this, but in any other gis data source i been working on a table has a defined geometry (or at least should have), so the above test would be obsolete. If one computes smallworld data (with it's very 'special' modelling approach) and has to test for existing or non-existing geometries, this post might be useful, i think.

Comment: That tag is for a proprietary product called "Smallworld", not for the small world concept (six degrees of separation and all that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you test for this attribute value as a text string using contains? Perhaps the NULL value is being treated as a string inside FME rather than a NULL.

[image: Tester transformer]

Comment: I didn't follow this internally string representation thing, because i did not succeed with `_x=#1.QNAN`, but the `Contains` suggestion really works! great!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and the workaround was to check the data before processing via [Geometry Validator](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/geometryvalidator.htm). If it does not have a geometry it comes through Failed port and is treated accordingly.

Also, the newer version of FME has [**Conditional Value** assignment](https://safe-software.gitbooks.io/fme-desktop-advanced-training-2016/content/DesktopAdvanced5Attributes/5.04.ConditionalValues.html) for Attribute Creator/Manager which has an operator **Has a value** (or something like that) that I have found very handy to treat NULL and its derivatives.

Comment: Good point checking the geometry before processing it. I checked out the test for 'has a value', but this fails for all features. strange.

Comment: I cannot access to FME right now so I cannot tell you for sure. You can check other operators out in the same group though to find out the one that works for you.

Answer (score 3):

I'd also suggest the GeometryFilter transformer as a way to filter out features that have no geometry.